# Cucumber Ruby - A step within a module

Tags: ruby, cucumber

**Background**

I'm writing both a cucumber library with a variety of different steps to use across multiple projects and attempting to reduce complexity of step definitions by splitting them into 3 different modules, for iOS, Android and Web - specifically projects that include all 3.

One of the steps libraries will include a load of security-based steps that I want to explicitly include into a project before using the steps.

The project split library will be explicitly included depending on what has been specified in the configuration:

```
if $profile[:app_type] == 'android'
   World(ProjectSteps::Android)
else 
   if $profile[:app_type] == 'ios'
      World(ProjectSteps::IOS)
   else
      World(ProjectSteps::Web)
   end
end
```

*These are not to replace the helper methods, but to save us time when starting up on new projects and will also allow us to have project specific step definitions written in different ways depending on whether we are testing the web, native iOS app or native Android app built to have the exact same functionality, but are different enough to require a different step definition*

**The Issue**

After defining the step within a module, the feature files can still execute this happily, even if the module has not been included in the "World" like this: `World(CommonSteps::Security)`, which is what you would usually use to let cucumber know about helper methods hidden away inside of modules.

```
When 'I provide my personal details' do
    select :title, 'Mr'
    fill :first_name, 'John'
    fill :last_name, 'Doe'

    unless $profile[:app_type] == 'web'
        click :progress
    end

    if $profile[:app_type] == 'android'
        fill :postcode, 'TE37ER'
        select :address, '1 Test Street'
        click :progress
        fill :occupation, 'Tester'
        fill :company, 'Test Company'
        click :progress
    else 
        fill :occupation, 'Tester'
        fill :company, 'Test Company'
        unless $profile[:app_type] == 'web'
           click :progress
        end
        fill :postcode, 'TE37ER'
        select :address, '1 Test Street'
        click :progress
    end
end
```

This step definition is trying to test 3 apps at once, but it is testing the exact same functionality, the exact same scenarios and the exact same features. If this was split into 3 step definitions, then it would be simpler to debug in the future, but the same feature file would be able to be used for each of them (which isn't out of the question, as there are many apps that share the exact same functionality across web and native mobile variants). In my opinion, this type of step definition is trying to achieve too much.

This would be easier to maintain despite being more, as it is simpler:

```
module ProjectSteps::IOS
   When 'I provide my personal details' do
       select :title, $user[:title]
       fill :first_name, $user[:first_name]
       fill :last_name, $user[:last_name]
       click :progress
       fill :occupation, $user[:occupation]
       fill :company, $user[:company]
       click :progress
       fill :postcode, $user[:postcode]
       select :address, $user[:line1]
       click :progress
   end
end
module ProjectSteps::Android
   When 'I provide my personal details' do
       select :title, $user[:title]
       fill :first_name, $user[:first_name]
       fill :last_name, $user[:last_name]
       click :progress
       fill :postcode, $user[:postcode]
       select :address, $user[:line1]
       click :progress
       fill :occupation, $user[:occupation]
       fill :company, $user[:company]
       click :progress
   end
end
module ProjectSteps::Web
   When 'I provide my personal details' do
       select :title, $user[:title]
       fill :first_name, $user[:first_name]
       fill :last_name, $user[:last_name]
       fill :occupation, $user[:occupation]
       fill :company, $user[:company]
       fill :postcode, $user[:postcode]
       select :address, $user[:line1]
       click :progress
   end
end
When 'some thing that is the same across platforms' do
   # Some stuff
end
```

Bear in mind, this is a simple version of what I'm trying to achieve, and doesn't show the full complexity of some of the issues that I'm trying to resolve. In this case, I would most likely go with the `if`/`unless` version rather than the split, but there are a few cases that are drastically more complex, and would benefit from being split into 3 sections.

We could also add silent checks for bugs that we found in development to make sure that these don't regress, and as the web, android and ios apps feature different bugs, we'd end up with a large amount of `if`/`unless` statements.

**What have I tried?** *- I hear you ask*

Well I'm either *really* close, or *really* far off.

`Given`, `When` and `Then` don't work as expected when within a different module, which is why I had to search for the method that I believe them to be an alias of.

Here is the resulting code:

```
require_relative 'xss.rb'
require 'cucumber'

module CommonSteps
  module Security
    Cucumber::RbSupport::RbDsl.register_rb_step_definition(
        'I attempt to write a step definition that has to be included to work', 
        Proc.new { 
            # Some stuff here
        })
  end
end
```

Registers the step definition absolutely fine. But that's part of the problem. I only want to register this step definition if the module has been included in the world of the project that I'm working on.

It would also mean that we can switch out the Web steps for the iOS and Android steps if we need to, while keeping the feature files the exact same. (Yes I know `if` statements are a thing, but too many, and step defs get complicated really fast.)

**Edit**

What I'm trying to achieve is not like the "Web steps" that we have seen in the past. No generic steps show code and are only in the language that we have agreed with the businesses that we work with, alongside the development team. As a lot of the projects we work on are cross platform, I'm in essence trying to achieve something that will switch which type of step definition is being used. - if you're using Chrome, use the Web version of this step definition, if you're using iOS, use the iOS version of this step definition, but also a means to include a variety of generic steps that are powered by text, which can link back to our page object model - keeping the scenarios completely business-based.

```
Given I am on the "Personal Details" page # (generic)
When I provide my personal details # (non-generic, but Web, iOS and Android versions exist)
But leave the "First Name" field blank # (generic)
And I attempt to continue to the next page # (generic)
Then I should see a validation error for the "First Name" text box stating: "Please provide your first name" # (generic)
```

For example, and if the validation is something that the business wants to know is working, and it'a part of the requirements that have been agreed with the business, is there a more business understandable way to communicate that information? - the why in this, is that we want to make sure the user fills in the information so that the validation does not show, but in the case that they don't provide that information, we should be also testing for the validation appearing in scenarios where it is needed.

We use the page object model in such a way that "Personal Details" will find the `:personal_details` key in the urls map. The key can be passed down to the next steps, linking to the `Pages.personal_details` method, which contains the `:first_name` key. All of our projects use this setup, and it's part of the documentation that goes with our core helper method library.

What I'm trying to achieve is not necessarily bad practice when used in the way that I'm suggesting, but could, if used incorrectly, be used as such.

Answer (score 0):

There have been quite a few times in Cucumber's history when things like this have been done Cucumber itself used to have web steps, which was removed some time ago. These are now in a Gem https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails-training-wheels. You might get some tips from that for your library.

That said, I would strongly recommend not writing a library of step definitions. Instead I would write a library of methods that can be used by step definitions. A crude example might help illustrate this.

Lets say you have a really complex method for logging in to an application. You could write a really commplicated step definition that deals with all sorts of logging in things such as

`When I login (hugely complex regex to deal with things like ...
   # loads of code to deal with you params and regex's and make things work with lots of different scenarios`

or you could write a method like

`def login(as:, args={})`

and let people use this method when they write stuff e.g.

```
When 'I login' do
  login as: @i
end

When 'I login as Fred' do
  login as: create_or_find_user(firstname: 'Fred')
end
```

or

```
When 'I login as Fred with Jill's password' do
  login as: @fred, password: @jill.password
end
```

The helper methods provide utility to help you write simple step definitions that are appropriate to your individual context. A shared step definition restricts you to using something that is highly complex and cannot have anything context specific.

Scenarios should be context specific and allow flexible simple language that is specific to the context of the individual World they are part of. They should be all about Why something is being done and What that thing is, and have nothing about How something is being done. By definition they do not share and so by definition neither to step definitions.

Once you've left a step definition by making a call you are into the realm of code, and code is really effective at sharing

Cucumber has learnt the lesson that shared step definitions are a really bad idea (see http://aslakhellesoy.com/post/11055981222/the-training-wheels-came-off). Be wary of repeating past mistakes.

Comment: The library of steps are for things like navigating to url's, security tests, and API tests, which can be very generic, and are for in-house purposes. But, they are only the ones that can be generic without showing any code to the feature files. I understand that writing steps that are more like : When I fill "#foo" with "Bar", is particularly bad practice, which is why I've grown away from using that.

Comment: Read the linked article and consider re-reading my answer. A scenario should never have a URL in it, thats HOW you are doing something, not WHY. Scenarios for API's shouldn't be about HOW you call the API they should be about WHY you are calling the API. There really are no generic scenarios! The whole point of scenarios is to write about things that are specific to a World, thats why Cucumber:World is called World and why things are global in it. Each thing in a scenario should be specific to the World and there should be no ambiguity in the World.

Comment: Perhaps consider giving specific examples of some steps you think are generic in separate questions and we can look at things in more detail

Comment: We work with the page object model in such a way that the "I am on the 'Personal Details' page" step links back to a hash map with the urls in it, and navigates to that page, and the map setup is always the same, as we have written a script that builds our basic skeleton framework for us to save time. It reads like human language, and is understandable by all. If the language needs to change, we can write another step for that specific project, where it is different. It's more of a time saving library for steps that can be cross project.

Comment: Everyone should focus on making cucumber suites that are easily understandable by all that are working on the project, that's something that I do not deny. What this is mainly for (other than the generic steps, as stated in the previous comment) is to allow duplication of step definitions where the goal is a cross platform suite that works with Web and Mobile together, using a configuration file to switch between which type of step is being used in the case that Web and Mobile interactions are sufficiently different that if statements would make the step definition do too much.

Comment: Try taking all this code out of the step definitions. Make `When I provide my personal details` a call to a method `provide_personal_details`. Once you are inside a ruby method then you can the programming language to sort out your problem, from basic if IOS do , to dynamic loading of modules. If you continue to write all your code in your step definitions you will struggle. If you pull your code out things will start working and you won't really need to share your step definitions as they are so simple there isn't really the need.